# How to embed user control (ascx) from code behind C#?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, user-controls, ascx

Embedding user controls into html page is easy but what about embedding user controls dynamically from code behind c#? Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`LoadControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf(v=vs.110).aspx) to load and create a control dynamically. Then you can add it to the page's control-collection.

```
UcType myControl = (UcType) LoadControl("UcType.ascx");
this.SomeContainerContainerControl.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

where `UcType` is the type of your `UserControl` and `SomeContainerContainerControl` is the control you want to add this uc like a `Panel`. 
If you want to add it on top of the page simply use `this.Controls.Add(myControl)`.

You should add it in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` (at the latest). You have to recreate it on every postback as every other dynamic control with the same ID as before (if any).

Comment: It should be `UcType myControl = (UcType) LoadControl("UcType.ascx");` (without the .cs) otherwise it throws an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Thanks for noting. I wasn't sure since [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also shows an example with `.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LoadControl() method and load it into a content control

example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    controls_example exmp = LoadControl("controls/example.ascx") as controls_example;
    myContentPanel.Controls.Add(exmp);
}
```